# Sidekiq query for job completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, graphql, sidekiq

I have an admin dashboard action in a react front end using a ruby on rails API back end. I have a sidekiq job that runs to import users from a third party. I would like to somehow trigger a refresh on the admin panel when the job is complete. What is the best way to go about this? I am using graphql-ruby. I could use start-polling on the front end maybe? Can I poll for completion of a specific job on sidekiq somehow? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Ilovebathroomlights

There are several approaches I can use, one of them I am writing below assuming you are okay to write a state to Redis, Database, or any storage you might be using and can be used to poll.

You can start by assigning a unique id to your sidekiq job, and save this id with status as "pending", at the last line inside the sidekiq job code, update the status of the unique id as "completed".

In meantime, you can poll by the unique id you generated for the particular job, and refresh the data or refresh the page.